# filled semicircle in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry, matlab-figure

Is there some good tip how to plot filled circle about specific point in Matlab? I've found solution for normal circle, but I dont know how fill it.

I need this because I should have circle with two different colors on each half of it. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a set of polygon vertices and plot them with `patch` or `fill` (full circle).

```
r = 1;
phi = 0:0.01:2*pi;
x = r*cos(phi);
y = r*sin(phi);
patch(x,y,'b');
axis equal;
```

This is a bit more code than the solution by [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450975/2903371). But it may be useful if you want to have a set of polygons and want to treat all polygons the same.

**EDIT**
This code will give 2 separately colored semi-circles.

```
r = 1;
phi = 0:0.01:pi;
x = r*cos(phi); x = [x,x(1)];
y = r*sin(phi); y = [y,y(1)];
patch(x,y,'b');
x2 = r*cos(pi+phi); x2 = [x2,x2(1)];
y2 = r*sin(pi+phi); y2 = [y2,y2(1)];
patch(x2,y2,'r');
axis equal;
```

Comment: This answer could be easily generalized to two half-circles with a different color on each, as the OP wants

Comment: @LuisMendo Right, I fixed that.

Comment: Thanks, I used this code to generate a half filled semicircle- I got it changed one `b` to `w`  and another `b` to `k`. I was wondering what was the need for commands like `x = [x,x(1)];`  `x2 = [x2,x2(1)];` and similar one. It is not making any change, at least to me. Am I making any wrong statement here?

Comment: @sreerajt Do you have a problem, or is it just a comment that x = [x,x(1)]? I tried this on 2020a and it works for me. As for `x = [x,x(1)];` the reason is lost in the sands of time. What the code does is to connect the last point of the graph back to the first point. I am not sure why I did so. It could be that the patch method caused a problem with this when the code was written, but it could also be a general intention to always connect figures.

Comment: @patrik , I am not facing any problem, but I was just curious as to what that part of the code does. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To plot a filled circle use [`rectangle`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) with the `'Curvature'` property equal to `[1 1]`, and set the `'Facecolor'` property to the desired fill color:

```
rectangle('Position',[10 10 20 20], 'Curvature',[ 1 1], 'Facecolor','b', 'Edgecolor','k');
axis equal
```

[image]

Comment: Matlab is so logic: a circle is a square with all four corners 100% round!